# Google Publish Localizations

Tags: java, android, google-play

By default with my Android app published, Google Publish adds all localizations. How is it possible to restrict this to specific localizations (in Publish or even in source code)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a documentation page about translations: [docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en)

Unfortunately, it says that if you don't provide translation, automatic one will be used:

> While it's best to use translations by native speakers, automated translations of your app's Store Listing will be available to Google
>   Play users.
>
> If users visit your app's Store Listing on Google Play in a language
>   that you haven't translated, they can choose to view an automated
>   translation of your app's page. Near the top of the page, there will
>   be a notification that explains the translation has been done
>   automatically, along with an option to view the Store Listing in its
>   default language instead.
>
> Note: Automated translations aren't available in Armenian,
>   Raeto-romance, Tagalog and Zulu.

Users can turn off the auto translation option, but developers can't push them, at least now.